# Xslt copy entire XML message into a node

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML message that I want to pull some metadata from, but I also would like to add as part of the message another node called "MessageXml" or something similar.

I've got it partly working so far using:

```
<xsl:template match="ns0:*">
    <xsl:element name="MessageXml">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

The problem is, that this doesn't copy over the namespaces into root node of the results of the `select="."`. I need the namespace.

So then I tried:

```
<xsl:template match="MyOriginalMessageRootNode">
    <MessageXml>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
    </MessageXml>
</xsl:template>
```

But then that just locks up XmlSpy in what I assume is some sort of recursive infinite loop. I feel like I'm really close, but I can't just get it to work exactly the way I want.

How can I preserve the namespaces while copying the entire message to a node?

The original message looks as such:

```
<ns0:ADT_ALL_25_GLO_DEF xmlns:ns0="http://microsoft.com/HealthCare/HL7/2X">
    <MSH>
       <MSH.2_EncodingCharacters>^~\&amp;</MSH.2_EncodingCharacters>
       <MSH.3_SendingApplication>
          <HD.0_NamespaceId>REG</HD.0_NamespaceId>
       </MSH.3_SendingApplication>
...SNIP...
</<ns0:ADT_ALL_25_GLO_DEF>
```

and I want the result:

```
 <root>
   <metadata>
     <somedata>
     </somedata>
   </metadata>
   <MessageXml>
      ...the message...
   </MessageXml>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns0="http://microsoft.com/HealthCare/HL7/2X"
exclude-result-prefixes="ns0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/ns0:ADT_ALL_25_GLO_DEF">
    <root>
        <metadata>
            <somedata>
            </somedata>
        </metadata>
        <MessageXml>
            <xsl:copy-of select="/"/>
        </MessageXml>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

applied to this well-formed(!) input example:

**XML**

```
<ns0:ADT_ALL_25_GLO_DEF xmlns:ns0="http://microsoft.com/HealthCare/HL7/2X">
    <MSH>
       <MSH.2_EncodingCharacters>^~\&amp;</MSH.2_EncodingCharacters>
       <MSH.3_SendingApplication>
          <HD.0_NamespaceId>REG</HD.0_NamespaceId>
       </MSH.3_SendingApplication>
    </MSH>
</ns0:ADT_ALL_25_GLO_DEF>
```

will return:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <metadata>
      <somedata/>
   </metadata>
   <MessageXml>
      <ns0:ADT_ALL_25_GLO_DEF xmlns:ns0="http://microsoft.com/HealthCare/HL7/2X">
         <MSH>
            <MSH.2_EncodingCharacters>^~\&amp;</MSH.2_EncodingCharacters>
            <MSH.3_SendingApplication>
               <HD.0_NamespaceId>REG</HD.0_NamespaceId>
            </MSH.3_SendingApplication>
         </MSH>
      </ns0:ADT_ALL_25_GLO_DEF>
   </MessageXml>
</root>
```